# Sitecore - System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

Hi and thank you for your help. We're trying to keep a Sitecore site up and running on a WS 2008 R2 Standard server but keep running into the following exception:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
>
> The site is set up to run in its own App Pool with the 2.0 framework
>   version selected and integrated pipeline mode.
>
> The site will run fine for a few minutes but then the app pool ends up
>   being stopped with the following details:
>
> "Application pool '######' is being automatically disabled due to a
>   series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool."
>
> Checking the Application log show the following:
>
> An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
>
> Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT
>
> Process ID: 5156
>
> Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
>
> Message: The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> StackTrace: at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32
>   hr)  at System.Security.Cryptography.SafeKeyHandle._FreeHKey(IntPtr
>   pKeyCtx)  at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.SafeKeyHandle.ReleaseHandle()  at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalFinalize()  at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing) 
>   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Finalize()

A tip on one site I found said to make sure that the account that the site is running under is a member of the Cryptographic Operators group which I did. Sadly the site continued to fail.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

## EDIT

After I implemented the first answer below I took another look at the server Application logs and it looks like every time the app pool goes down the following warning happens first:

> Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other
>   applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The
>   applications or services that hold your registry file may not function
>   properly afterwards.
>
> Event 1530, User Profile Service  DETAIL -   2 user registry handles
>   leaked from
>   \Registry\User\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965:
>   Process 3260
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965
>   Process 3260
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates

And another example:

> Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other
>   applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The
>   applications or services that hold your registry file may not function
>   properly afterwards.
>
> DETAIL -   13 user registry handles leaked from
>   \Registry\User\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965:
>   Process 5228
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965
>   Process 5228
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965
>   Process 5228
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965
>   Process 5228
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965
>   Process 5228
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\TrustedPeople
>   Process 5228
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\trust
>   Process 5228
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion Process 5228
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates
>   Process 5228
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root
>   Process 5228
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\SmartCardRoot
>   Process 5228
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My
>   Process 5228
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\CA
>   Process 5228
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3231641130-1035467585-39029555-2466166849-1382764965\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might help: [Running Sitecore 6 on Windows 7′S IIS](http://www.depl0y.com/?p=386).

It basically says to add this in your `global.asax`:

```
public void Application_Start() {
  System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
  System.Security.Cryptography.DSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
}
```

Comment: This was the solution that ended up fixing it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the application pool to 4.0 framework fixed the issue.