# SiteCore - System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException  - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have problem while loading the default page of an sitecore site. Error in log is as follows:

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was unhandled
  Message=The system cannot find the path specified.

Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.SafeKeyHandle._FreeHKey(IntPtr pKeyCtx)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.SafeKeyHandle.ReleaseHandle()
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalFinalize()
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Finalize()
  InnerException: null

Any help appreciated well in advance.

Thanks

ANS

Tried with setting Load User Profile = True on the app pool. Did not resolve my issue :(

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify which version of Sitecore you are running, but  Sitecore CMS 6.0.1 rev.090317 (also known as "6.0.1 Update-1") should address this.

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog.aspx

> Fixed: When the IIS application pool was configured to run using a non-standard user account Identity, a System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException might occur, preventing Sitecore from working.

You may also want to take a look at this question:
[Sitecore - System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504760/sitecore-system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception)

Comment: @SeanKearney, Thanks. I'm using Sitecore.NET 6.1.0 (rev. 090821). AppPool has NetworkSecurity as identity.  Before posting, I had given a try to modify global.asax. It did not help. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Did you look at the link Yan posted on the linked question? http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Fixing%20Cryptographic%20Errors.aspx

Comment: Regrets for not putting my comments here: Not sure but probably this might be the case sometime - Though the database names matching connection string config file, the database backup taken was from different database. Connecting to the valid DBs resolved this issue for me.