# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException" occurred in w3wp.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, cryptography

Any help for how to get out of this error?

**An unhandled exception "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException" occurred in w3wp.exe**

I'm getting this error whenever I browse for the site I have setup in IIS 
(version 7.5.7600.16385)

Other info:
.Net framework: 2.0
PipeLine mode: integrated
AppPool ID: NetworkService
Load User Profile : true

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE:
I'm just trying to load default page.

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was unhandled
  Message=The system cannot find the path specified.

Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.SafeKeyHandle._FreeHKey(IntPtr pKeyCtx)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.SafeKeyHandle.ReleaseHandle()
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalFinalize()
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Finalize()
  InnerException: null

Comment: What is the page that you are going to trying to do?

Comment: Can we also get the full stack trace?  Is this happening in custom code?

Comment: @Stefan, Thanks for the quick response. I have updated question above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[Sitecore - System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504760/sitecore-system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception)

Not sure what the problem is - but it sounds similar

Comment: I had tried with that. It did not help. Thanks for your time.